# real time interface in ur5 robot

Tags: ros, universal-robots, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am writing my final bachelor project. I have to run an Universal UR5 robot with speech recognition. At the moment I have signs like "right", "left", etc. in python.

So I've got a few questions.
Is it possible to have an real time interface in the ur5 robot and the simulation?
Do you have any ideas how to realise this? I read about an moveit interface with python. Is it working with this in real time?

I would be very greatful for any help =)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199838/real-time-interface-in-ur5-robot/) by [Jan Moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21179/jan-moritz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-12-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-12-19**:
Could you clarify what you exactly mean with "real time interface". Do you need hard real-time 1kHz force/velocity control for instance, or is 10Hz position control sufficient? The quality of the answers will probably depend on what your requirements are.

**Comment by [Jan Moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21179/jan-moritz/) on 2014-12-22**:
10 Hz position control is ok. do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on the requirements you state (and the fact that you haven't mentioned it yet), I'd take a look at the [universal_robot](http://wiki.ros.org/universal_robot) package. It can probably do what you want.

---

The wiki page is a bit barren, but the `README.md` file in the [github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot) repository should clear things up.

Note that the driver provides just a `FollowJointTrajectoryAction` server. You'll have to write a client yourself ([ur_driver/test_move.py](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/blob/hydro-devel/ur_driver/test_move.py) shows a minimal example of how to do this).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3